# for loop variable name use swift

Tags: swift, variables, for-loop

I have static variable name which I want to create it use loop :

```
var imageke1 = ""
var imageke2 = ""
var imageke3 = ""
var imageke4 = ""
var imageke5 = ""
var imageke6 = ""
var imageke7 = ""
```

I try with this but create error expected pattern:

```
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++
    {
        var "imageke\(i)" = ""
    }
```

I try too with this but it conflict with same variable name (kucing) :

```
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++
    {
        var kucing = "imageke\(i)"
        var kucing = ""
    }
```

At the end I also create list of string as result, and I want to change it too with loop:

```
var names: [String] = ["\(imageke1)", "\(imageke2)", "\(imageke3)", "\(imageke4)", "\(imageke5)", "\(imageke6)", "\(imageke7)"]
```

How to loop this variable name (imageke) and var names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var names: [String] = []

for index in 1...8 {
    names.append("imageke\(index)")
}

println(names)  // "[imageke1, imageke2, imageke3, imageke4, imageke5, imageke6, imageke7, imageke8]"
```

Comment: thanks, this help me on var names but I still have problem to loop variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of a string array instead of manually retrieving variables.

```
var imageke = [String]() //remember to set your arraySize, or append new elements
// to set 
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++
{
    imageke[i] = "some value here"
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work, error on i inside var imageke[i]

Comment: should be  imageke[i] = "some value here" I updated the code as well.