# Variable in label Name - Swift

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use a variable in a label name.

For example, my label is called `button1text` and I have a variable `var x = 1`.

Is there a way to do this`button(x)text`?

Comment: You should check out [dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321778/swift-converting-a-string-into-a-variable-name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175358/for-loop-variable-name-use-swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585591/how-can-i-access-to-variable-name-and-change-string-to-it

Comment: This question is a pure Swift question, there is no need for watchkit tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not have variable name in identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are evaluated at compile time, so no, it's not possible (at runtime).

Alternatively use an array or assign tags to the labels and get the label with `viewWithTag`

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection with `Mirror`. The capabilities are very limited in the context you want but you can try something like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

    @IBAction func didTapGoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            if let v = child.label, v == "button2" {
                (child.value as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text = "changed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```